# SQL sort by two columns - date and time zone

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I'm trying to provide sorting functionality by two columns:

```
  START_DATE_TIME               TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL,
  START_DATE_TIME_ZONE          VARCHAR2(255)               NULL,
```

The regular data that I save in these columns looks like this:

```
START_DATE_TIME: 29.10.2017 01:00:00,000000000
START_DATE_TIME_ZONE: America/Los_Angeles
```

I tried just the regular order by:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    event
ORDER BY
    start_date_time ASC,
    start_date_time_zone ASC
```

But, as I was probably expected, it wasn't sorted correctly. Time zone is sorted as word, not as the offset. What I want to achieve here is to get the time zone applied to the time I have in UTC in order to get the exact point in time which I can use for my sorting. Is there a way to achive that using the structure that I have or I will have to merge my two columns and store time zones there? e.g.

```
  START_DATE_TIME            TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
```

Basically I'm using Spring Data + Oracle.

Comment: You need to sort according to UTC (or similar), i.e. same time zone.

Comment: The time zone is determined by the second column. How can I get the result in UTC without having applied this time zone?

Comment: You need to apply the TZ to the datetime and then sort by the result.

Comment: Do you mean I can do it on demand without prior modification to DB?

Comment: You don't need to modify the database. You could possibly use a WITH statement to produce a materialized sub-query containing the offsets for each TZ, then join to that by the TZ text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
select to_timestamp_tz(START_DATE_TIME || ' ' || START_DATE_TIME_ZONE)
from . . .
```

As an example, you can run:

```
select to_timestamp_tz(timestamp '2017-10-29 01:00:00.000000000' || ' America/Los_Angeles')
```

Comment: Your option works. As well as this: START_DATE_TIME_WITH_ZONE AS (FROM_TZ(START_DATE_TIME, START_DATE_TIME_ZONE)). Thanks!